# python split map into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data as below:

| ID | country |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | {"23":1,"45":1,"65":1} |
| 02 | {"23":1,"48":1} |
| 03 | {"65":1} |

And I want to split/explode it like this:

| ID | country |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 23 |
| 01 | 45 |
| 01 | 65 |
| 02 | 23 |
| 02 | 48 |
| 03 | 65 |

how can I do this in python or SQL? P.S., for all the country keys, the value is :1.

Comment: `df.explode('country')` ?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, the df output is the same.. maybe I need to cast it as a dict or something?

Comment: You might have strings in the `country` column. Convert it to dict first `df['country'] = df['country'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`: https://akuiper.com/console/JH10BYmcC49H

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':['01', '02','03'], 'country':[{"23":1,"45":1,"65":1}, {"23":1,"48":1}, {"65":1}]})
df
```

Dataframe:

```
    ID  country
0   01  {'23': 1, '45': 1, '65': 1}
1   02  {'23': 1, '48': 1}
2   03  {'65': 1}
```

Using [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df.explode('country', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    ID  country
0   01  23
1   01  45
2   01  65
3   02  23
4   02  48
5   03  65
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a dataframe `df`

```
data = {'ID':['01', '02', '03'], 
        'country':[{"23":1,"45":1,"65":1}, 
                                             {"23":1,"48":1},{"65":1}]

       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    ID  country
0   01  {'23': 1, '45': 1, '65': 1}
1   02  {'23': 1, '48': 1}
2   03  {'65': 1}
 
df.explode('country').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   ID   country
0   01  23
1   01  45
2   01  65
3   02  23
4   02  48
5   03  65
```